# Javascript / Jquery custom event based on state of multiple variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have multiple variables in javascript( say for example aValue, bValue, cValue). All these variables are initially set to 0. Now I have multiple functions / events which change these values as per my custom logic. When all these three variable values become 1, I want a new event to be triggered by which I can alter the DOM.

```
var aValue = 0;
var bValue = 0;
var cValue = 0;

// On doing something functionA is called
functionA() {
  aValue = 1;
}

//On triggering some event function is called
$(selector).on(event, function() {
  bValue = 1;
});

//On doing something functionC is called
functionC() {
 cValue = 1;
}
```

I need to trigger an event when all these functions are invoked (thereby changing all the variables to 1). By using this event I want to change the DOM.

Something like

```
$(selector).on(// when aValue == 1 && bValue == 1 && cValue == 1, function(){
  // do something
});
```

Is there a way to do it.

Comment: Have a common function inside all 3 functions which will be invoked after change in the value and if all the values are changed, do next action...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a function, call it each time you modify any of the values

```
var aValue = 0;
var bValue = 0;
var cValue = 0;

function testAll() {
  if(aValue  == 1 && bValue   == 1 && cValue   == 1){
    alert('triggered all');
  };
}

// On doing something functionA is called
functionA() {
  aValue = 1;
  testAll();
}

//On triggering some event function is called
$(selector).on(event, function () {
  bValue = 1;
  testAll();
});

//On doing something functionC is called
functionC() {
  cValue = 1;
  testAll();
}
```

Comment: `aValue == bValue == cValue == 1` doesn't do what you think it does - `0 == 0 == 1` is actually `true`, so this doesn't work.

Comment: Always prefer ___`===`___ over `==`

Answer (score 1):

Create another function and check there values in it

```
functionA() {
  aValue = 1;
  checkValue();
}

//On triggering some event function is called
$(selector).on(event, function() {
  bValue = 1;
  checkValue();
});

//On doing something functionC is called
functionC() {
 cValue = 1;
 checkValue();
}


function checkValue(){
    if(aValue  == 1 && bValue   == 1 && cValue   == 1){
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a bit more complicated but will give you a lot more freedom. Lets say you have multiple functions / events which change these values, so the other solutions will require you to call another function from a lot of places making hard to maintain.

You should consider using a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

> The Proxy object is used to define custom behavior for fundamental
>   operations (e.g. property lookup, assignment, enumeration, function
>   invocation, etc).

You can have a single object and add all the variables you need as properties and using `Proxy` add a `set()` and `get()` functions to listen for the changes to you values

```
var handler = {
    get: function(target, name){
        return name in target?
            target[name] : 0;
    },
    set: function(target, name, value){
        var firstTime = !(name in target);
        target[name] = value;
        if (firstTime) return value;
        for (var key in target) {
          if (target.hasOwnProperty(key) && target[key] !== 1) {
            return value;
          }
        }
        alterDOM();
    }
};

function alterDOM(){
    // do your stuff
    console.log('All properties are = 1!');
};

var values = new Proxy({}, handler);
```

Now the `get()` is making all the properties of your object `= 0` by default, so if you do `console.log(values.a, values.b, values.c);` you will get `0 0 0`

The `set()` is setting the value to your properties but is also checking if all the properties are `= 1` and if so the firing the `alterDOM()` function where you can add all your logic.

So if you do

```
values.a = 1;
values.b = 1;
values.c = 1;
```

The `alterDOM()` will be fired

Please note this is independent of the number of properties you add, so it will work the same if you have 3, 5 or 100 variables to work with, without changing the code.